# Responsive extension is not working with row grouping

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want my application be accessed by mobile devices. I implement http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/wm9yerny/ in my application. But If use row grouping, it's not working.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').dataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bJQueryUI": true
            }).rowGrouping({
                fnOnGrouped: function(groups){
                    console.log("Groups", groups);

                    for(key in groups){
                        if(groups.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                            var data =  $('#example').dataTable().fnGetData($(groups[key].groupItemClass).get(0));
                            $(groups[key].nGroup).css('background-color',  data[4] );
                        }
                    }                   
                }
            });
        });
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you tell us what, if any, error messages you are getting? If your not getting any error messages can you explain what "not working" means for your issue.

Comment: @alstonp, Sorry, my english is not so good. I use responsive datatables ([link](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/ebRXw/)) so my appication can be access by mobile. But if it is combined with row grouping datatables, the application can not be accessed by mobile.